# Displaying a badge counter in a tab

Tags: angular

I want to display a counter badge which displays number of the current packages uploaded next to it's tab, but when I appended the component with badge, the badge is being displayed only when I click on this tab. It should automatically detect the change and display the counter.

Can you point me in the right direction what might be wrong here? Thank you.

//Packgage to reviev

.HTML

```
   <nav fd-tab-nav>
      <div fd-tab-item *ngFor="let link of navLinks; let i = index">
        <a fd-tab-link [active]="activeLinkIndex == i" [routerLink]="link.link">
          <span class="fd-tab" fd-tab-tag>
            {{ link.label }}
            <p
              *ngIf="link.showActiveInstallationsCounter && activeInstallationsCount$ | async as activeInstallationsCount"
              class="fd-tabs__count"
            >
              {{ activeInstallationsCount }}
            </p>
            <p *ngIf="link.showPackagesToReviewCounter && (packagesToReviewCounter$ | async) as packagesToReviewCounter" class="fd-tabs__count">
              {{ packagesToReviewCounter }}
            </p>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

.TS

```
  {
        label: 'User Packages',
        link: 'user-packages',
        index: 4
      },
      {
        label: 'Approve Packages',
        link: 'approve-packages',
        index: 5,
        showPackagesToReviewCounter: true
      },
      {
        label: 'Manage Repositories',
        link: 'manage-repositories',
        index: 6
      }
    ]);
```

[image]

Comment: Which library are you using for tab creation ?

Comment: fundamentals-ngx

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without stackblitz / code responsible for providing the actual count.

My best guess, considering limited amount of code shown, would be that `packagesToReviewCounter$` observable doesn't emit until you  have clicked on the tab. Hence the `packagesToReviewCounter` resolved to `undefined`, and whole `ngIf` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

As per the sap documentations you should use use the tab link https://github.com/SAP/fundamental-ngx/blob/38d3ebadc84389d9a668ef2cab249db2b0a2cf83/libs/core/src/lib/tabs/tab-link/tab-link.directive.ts
utils as below

```
* <a fd-tab-link>
 *    link
 * </a>
```

So please make correction in your link codeas below and it should work then for you.

```
<a fd-tab-link [active]="activeLinkIndex == i" [routerLink]="link.link">
          <span class="fd-tab" fd-tab-tag>
            {{ link.label }}</span>
            <span
              *ngIf="link.showActiveInstallationsCounter && activeInstallationsCount$ | async as activeInstallationsCount"
              class="fd-tabs__count"
            >
              {{ activeInstallationsCount }}
            </Span>
            <span *ngIf="link.showPackagesToReviewCounter && (packagesToReviewCounter$ | async) as packagesToReviewCounter" class="fd-tabs__count">
              {{ packagesToReviewCounter }}
            </span>
      
        </a>
```